# MySQL - UPDATE + Query optimalization

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I'am having an optimalization problem. I am not really into MySQL Indexes yet. I read a few articles and questions but I haven't found what I am looking for.

I have an UPDATE statement with a WHERE condition on a table having nearly 1 million rows.

I want to speed up this UPDATE operation. I think most of the time is spent by looking for a the record specified in the WHERE.

My queries look like this, with different URLs:

```
UPDATE table SET updated = 1, updated_date = now() , [some more fields updated]
WHERE url = 'someurl.com?id=123532js23';
```

URLs are unique. Currently there is an AUTO INREMENT id field defined as a PRIMARY KEY. I dont need any <, > or BETWEEN operations - so maybe could I use some hashing?

What engine and indexing should I use for best performance?

One of my friends suggested to use InnoDB + UNIQUE on url field. Is there anything else I can do? 
This UPDATE runs really many times - about 1 000 000 times each day and most of the executions results in updating - about 95%.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One of my friends suggested to use InnoDB + UNIQUE on url field. Is there anything else I can do? This UPDATE runs really many times - about 1 000 000 times each day and most of the executions results in updating - about 95%.

You friend is right.

One thing is that `URL` may be long and the maximum possible length of an index key on `InnoDB` is `767` bytes.

Thus, you would better hash the urls (say, with `MD5`) and create a `UNIQUE` index on the field containing the url's hash (and of course use it in the `WHERE` condition):

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (url, hashed_url, ...)
VALUES  ('someurl.com?id=123532js23', MD5('someurl.com?id=123532js23'))

UPDATE  mytable
SET     ...
WHERE   hashed_url = MD5('someurl.com?id=123532js23')
```